# How to create a morris.js line chart with multiple lines and groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, morris.js

I have a bunch of @employees that receive Votes.

I am using the code below to show on a graph a count of the total votes received by all the employees in all the businesses per month.

In the view:

```
<%= content_tag :div, "", id: "employee_vote_count_chart", data: {votes: Vote.chart_data(2.months.ago)} %>
```

In the models and controllers:

```
Vote belongs_to :employee
Employee has_many :votes

Vote.chart_data

def self.chart_data
 total_count = count_by_month(start)
 start = start.to_date.beginning_of_month
 today = Date.today.beginning_of_month
 range = (start..today).select {|d| d.day == 1}
  range.map do |month|
  {
   month: month,
   total_votes: total_count[month] || 0
  }
 end
end

def self.count_by_month(start)
 enquiries = unscoped.where(created_at: start.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now)
 enquiries = enquiries.group("date_trunc('month', created_at)")
 enquiries = enquiries.select("date_trunc('month', created_at) as created_at, count(*) as count")
 enquiries.each_with_object({}) do |enquiry, counts|
  counts[enquiry.created_at.to_date] = enquiry.count
 end
end
```

I want to modify the code so that it returns how many votes each employee received per month in a particular business.

Currently it returns data for total_votes for all employees and all businesses per month:

```
data: [
    { month: 'january 2013', total_votes: 180 },
    { month: 'february 2013', total_votes: 190 },
    { month: 'march 2013', total_votes: 180 }
  ]
```

I want the code to return data with each employees total per month and restrict it to a certain business:

```
  data: [
    { month: 'january 2013', employee_1: 100, employee_2: 80 },
    { month: 'february 2013', employee_1: 100, employee_2: 90 },
    { month: 'march 2013', employee_1: 80, employee_2: 100 }
  ]
```

I am using rails 3, postgresql, morris.js.

Comment: Can you provide a the schema for those tables, because is not clear how do you get the business.